# guess = raw_input() when i press enter button what will the value of the guess variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

`guess = raw_input()`: if I press enter button here what will be the value inside the guess variable and is it printable?

Executable code in shell IDE:

```
>>> guess = raw_input()

>>> print guess
```

Comment: What's with the tag soup?!

Comment: Print the representaion of `guess` and see: `print repr(guess)`

Answer (score 1):

If you press enter then `guess=''`.

You can print `guess` which will turn out to be blank.